# Angular2 : trouble in integrating ng2-select

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing really tough problem and I hope anybody can help me! I already find a lot of question here about the same problem but I applied what found as solution but it is still not working!

So I have a application in Angular 2 and I am trying to integrate the ng2-select and it's returning the boring error:

> angular2-polyfills.js:332 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I know everybody is telling that it's a problem with my System.config but I can't solve it!

So there is my code!

**System.config**

```
System.config({
map: {
    'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap',
    'ng2-select': 'node_modules/ng2-select'
},
packages: {
    src: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
});
System.import('src/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from "./components/app/app.component";

import 'ng2-select';
import 'ng2-bootstrap';

bootstrap(<any> AppComponent);
```

**my Component**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {select} from "ng2-select";

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'src/views/lead/lists.view.html',
    directives: [select],
})
export class LeadListsComponent {
    team: string = "Ringo";
    teams: string[] = ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"];
}
```

[I have the files on the node_modules/ng2-angular properly I think! There is the print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlzXJ.png)

But there is only TS files... could be that the problem? What should I do?

**-----UPDATE-----**

There is my tsconfig.json as well!

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please share a plundkr of your code ?

Comment: Is there any way to uso npm on plundkr? I don't know very well how to share my script as it is there!

Comment: @GustavoBissolli did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No I didn't @MrFoh =/... It was my first project in Angular2 and I had so many troubles unsolved so I gave up Angular2 and start using Vue.js for a while because I was out of time! But I really want to get another project to do in Angular2

Comment: @GustavoBissolli didn't think it would be this difficult to integrate a simple directive

Comment: @MrFoh I believe in you but I am new in that think of Framework front end! I always worked with jQuery (I know it sucks)... I have made one simple project in angular 1 and it was incredible! Much easier then how I was used to work... but with angular 2 because of Type Script I think it got a little tough to me! Actually my entire problem was to make jquery plugins work with angular since I am using templates from ThemeForest!

Comment: @GustavoBissolli Have you find solution? Have same problem.

Comment: No, I didn't man =/... Actually I gave up Angular and start to working with VueJS... now that I understand better the concept of front-end framework I am thinking about give other shoot with Angular!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is when you do an import for select your name is wrong:

In `MyComponent` you should be pulling it in like this:

```
import {Select} from "ng2-select";
```

Where the S in select is capitalized.  Usually when you get a:

> angular2-polyfills.js:332 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

It means a 404 error, that your module did not load correctly.   But ng2-select exports `Select` and not `select`.

You may also have to do:

```
import {Select} from "ng2-select/select";
```

I am not 100% sure how npm loads it into your node modules directory as I have not used it.

Comment: I've tried every single combination but it is still throwing this error! I am now instaling the "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter" and then I'll try to integrate the ng2-select and let you know!

Comment: Dores not work! I quite! Hahahah... May be could be a problem on the component no? I will try to do it on punkler and share here!

Comment: Does ng2-select come transpiled?  Hopefully webpack works, but what a pain in the butt!

Comment: What do you mean transpiled? Inside my node_modules/ng2-select there is the TS and the JS file! First of all I thought that would be the problem but I've checked and both files were there!

Comment: Yeah I figured you probably did, was just checking.  Try and put up a plunker and comment back and I'll try and play around with it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `ng2-select`, Well things have changed a bit. You have to change your systemjs configuration to below:

**systemjs.config.js**

```
map: {
   ...,

   'ng2-select': 'node_modules/ng2-select',

   ...
},
packages: {
  ....,
  'ng2-select': {main:'ng2-select.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}
}
```

add import statement below in your Module

```
import { SelectModule } from "ng2-select/ng2-select";
```

then add "SelectModule" to the NgModule.imports array.

Now in your component add the following import statement:

```
import { SelectComponent } from "ng2-select/ng2-select";
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much, You saved my day :) Thanks :)

Comment: You are most welcome and guess what! These is the first time I have answered a question on SO

Comment: Thanks Bro, Appreciate that

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar can you help me out with the implementation of the ng2-select. Cant find my way around it after having successfully installed it

Comment: LOL, its same here, I spent 4+ hours on it, I've successfully created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/dHN7gLigIEockfIYVdAe?p=preview).. but I'm not able to make it working in my application(big), it has some problem with `SelectModule` import.. but about an hour ago I figured out how to fix it.. :D but not sure its correct way or not.. Thanks :)

Comment: I would love to look at it. Quite apart from this I observed some anormalies in the associated tsconfig file "  "files": [
    "./demo/custom-typings.d.ts",
    "./ng2-select.ts"
  ] ". This two files are missing from my installation but are always specified in the tsconfig file so i have to manually delete the whole "file" section   to get my application to work

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is the following

in **systemjs.config.js**:

inside **map**  add : `'ng2-select': 'node_modules/ng2-select'`

inside **packages** add : `'ng2-select': {main:'ng2-select.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}`

then import like this: `import {SELECT_DIRECTIVES} from "ng2-select";`

Answer (score -1):

import { SELECT_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-select';